# Questão de concurso: código em Java acerca de sobre-escrita de métodos

Tags: java

Fiz uma prova de concurso e caiu a seguinte questão:

> Assinale a alternativa correspondente ao resultado da execução do método main do programa Java apresentado abaixo:
>
> ```
> public class A {
>
> public void ml(){
>     mx();
> }
>
> public static void main(String[] args){
>
>     A a = ( B) new C(); 
>     a.m1();
>     B b = (B) new A(); 
>     b.m1();
> }
>
> public void mdx(){ 
>      System.out.print(10);
> }
> }
>
>
> class B extends A{
> public void mx(){
>     System.out.print(30);
> }
> }
>
> class C extends B {
> public void mx(){
>     System.out.print(40);
> }
> }
> ```
>
> a) Serão impressos o valor 40 e o valor 10
> b) Serão impressos o valor 40 e o valor 30
> c) Serão impressos o valor 10 e o valor 10
> d) Será impresso o valor 40 e posteriormente será lançada a exceção ClassCastException
> e) Será impresso o valor 10 e posteriormente será lançada a exceção ClassCastException

Obs: Vi que existe um espaço em branco em: `( B)`

O gabarito diz que a correta é a letra D, mas estou com dúvidas nessa questão. Este gabarito está correto? Se sim, por quê? E se não, também, por quê?

Comment: Se o código que você postou for igual ao que esta na prova nenhuma esta correta.

Comment: Esta pergunta está sendo discutida no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5743/101

Comment: Esse espacinho no casting para a classe B não influencia em nada.

Answer (score 15):

Há erros de compilação neste código:

- Dentro do método `ml()` de `A`, o método `mx()` invocado não existe na classe `A`. Acho que era para o método `mdx` ser chamado de `mx`.
- No `main` está sendo invocado um método chamado `m1`, e não `ml`. Acho que era para esses nomes serem iguais.

[Veja isso não funcionando no ideone:](http://ideone.com/SpLknw)

> ```
> Main.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
>     mx();
>     ^
>   symbol:   method mx()
>   location: class A
> Main.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
>     a.m1();
>      ^
>   symbol:   method m1()
>   location: variable a of type A
> Main.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
>     b.m1();
>      ^
>   symbol:   method m1()
>   location: variable b of type B
> 3 errors
> ```

<sub><sup>Nota: Esse `Main.java` é porque estou compilando no ideone (e tive que tirar o `public` da declaração de `A`), isso é apenas uma limitação do ideone. Se você for compilar você mesmo, ele vai mostrar `A.java` ao invés de `Main.java`.</sup></sub>

Corrigindo-se esses erros de compilação, é exibido 40 e então um `ClassCastException` é lançado, tal como versa a alternativa D.

Na linha `A a = ( B) new C();`, o cast é válido porque embora `C` esteja sendo instanciado, temos que `C extends B`, então o cast para `B` é válido. Além disso, uma referência a `B` pode ser atribuída a uma variável do tipo `A` porque `B extends A`.

O fato de ter um espaço dentro do cast é irrelevante, pois o processo de tokenização do compilador (o que picota o código-fonte em tokens), irá separar o cast em três tokens: O abre-parênteses, o tipo do cast (`B`) e o fecha-parênteses. Os espaços não interferem com esse processo.

A chamada a `a.m1()` vai chamar o método `m1` do objeto que está na referência `a`. Este objeto é aquele do `new C()`, logo é do tipo `C`. A classe `C` sobre-escreve o método `m1` herdado de `B` e de `A`. Logo, o que vai ser executado é o método `m1` da classe `C`, que imprime 40.

Na linha `B b = (B) new A();`, temos que não é verdade que `A extends B`, logo isso vai dar um `ClassCastException`. O compilador permite isso porque o resultado da subexpressão `new A()` é do tipo `A`. Um cast de `A` para `B` é permitido pelo compilador porque existe relação de herança entre essas classes.

[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/94HinE) Neste código, eu fiz as correções sugeridas no começo e adicionei um `try-catch` dentro do `main` para que ele possa mostrar a exceção adequadamente.

Comment: Portanto dá para pedir impugnação da questão, né?

Comment: @bigown Supondo que ele a tenha digitado aqui corretamente.

Comment: Evidentemente :)

Answer (score 2):

Se na classe A em

```
public void m1()
{
    mx();
}
```

fosse

```
public void m1()
{
    mdx();
}
```

Então a letra **e** seria a resposta certa.

Mas se na classe A, se o método **mdx**, se chamasse ao invés disso, de **mx**,  então a letra **d** seria a resposta certa.

Mas do jeito que está digitado atualmente a resposta é "Não compila" porque mx não existe na classe A. Não importa se existe mx nos filhos, a busca pelo método é sempre feita no objeto atual e nos pais, nunca nos filhos.

Segue o código da classe A que faria a letra "**d**" ser a correta:

```
package testes;

public class A 
{
    public void m1()
    {
        mx();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        A a = ( B) new C(); 
        a.m1();

        B b = (B) new A(); 
        b.m1();

    }

    public void mx()
    { 
         System.out.print(10);
    }
}
```

O que se aprende analisando esse exercício especificamente no trecho abaixo?

```
        A a = ( B) new C(); 
        a.m1();
```

Aprende-se que o método que será executado é sempre o do objeto em questão, ou seja, o último que sobrescreveu o método, nesse caso foi o do objeto C. Caso não existisse esse método no objeto em questão, tentaria chamar o do pai, que é B, e caso não existisse o método no pai, tentaria chamar o do avô, que é A, subindo na hierarquia até achar o método. Como existe m1 em C, ele executa esse e não os outros.

Lembre-se que o objeto é criado quando se usa a palavra **new**. C foi armazenado como um B e B foi armazenado como um A, mas na essência continua sendo C.
Isto serve para permitir o Polimorfismo, segue um exemplo abaixo retirado do DevMedia:

```
abstract class Mamífero {
    public abstract double obterCotaDiariaDeLeite();
}

class Elefante extends Mamífero {
    public double obterCotaDiariaDeLeite(){
        return 20.0;
    }
}

class Rato extends Mamifero {
    public double obterCotaDiariaDeLeite() {
        return 0.5;
    }
}

class Aplicativo {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Polimorfismo\n");
        Mamifero mamifero1 = new Elefante();
        System.out.println("Cota diaria de leite do elefante: " + mamifero1.obterCotaDiariaDeLeite());
        Mamifero mamifero2 = new Rato();
        System.out.println("Cota diaria de leite do rato: " + mamifero2.obterCotaDiariaDeLeite());
    }
}
```

Referência: [Artigo no DevMedia: Encapsulamento, Polimorfismo, Herança em Java](http://www.devmedia.com.br/encapsulamento-polimorfismo-heranca-em-java/12991)