# Cast múltiplos em java

Tags: java, cast

Estou com dificuldades em fazer um exercício, porque não sei resolver este tipo de casting:

A classe `D` é a superclasse.

A classe `C` é a subclasse.

```
 D d = (D) (C) new D();
```

Ficaria grata se alguem me podesse ajudar.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181591/132 - Isso te ajuda?

Comment: `new (D)` não é uma sintaxe válida em Java. Isso vai dar um erro de compilação.

Comment: @VictorStafusa desculpa fui eu que me enganei e queria dizer new D()

Comment: @Articuno já está traduzido

Comment: @Rita o que deseja fazer? Esse casting está estranho..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos supor que tenhamos este código:

```
public class C {}

public class D extends C {}
```

Ou seja, tudo aquilo que **é um** `D`, também é um `C`. Mas o contrário não necessariamente é verdadeiro.

E então isso:

```
D d = (D) (C) new D();
```

Que é uma forma concisa de escrever o que pode ser interpretado com essas quatro etapas:

```
D temp1 = new D();   // Etapa 1
C temp2 = (C) temp1; // Etapa 2
D temp3 = (D) temp2; // Etapa 3
D d = temp3;         // Etapa 4
```

O que cada etapa faz:

1. `new D()` cria um objeto do tipo `D`.
2. O cast para `C` verifica se o objeto é do tipo `C`. Como o compilador sabe que todo `D` é um `C`, então esse cast é válido. A subexpressão resultante é do tipo `C`.
3. O cast para `D` verifica se o objeto é do tipo `C`. Como o compilador sabe que nem todo `C` **é um** `D`, então uma verificação será feita em tempo de execução. Se o objeto do tipo `C` não for um `D`, um `ClassCastException` será lançado. Neste caso, essa verificação sempre será bem sucedida. A subexpressão resultante é do tipo `D`.
4. O valor resultante é atribuído à variável `d`. Como o compilador sabe que o que está a direita do sinal de `=` é do tipo `D` e a variável `d` também é do tipo `D`, então essa atribuição é válida.

Observe que há dois tipos de *casts* aqui. Um deles (o da etapa 2) é um *upcasting* e o outro (o da etapa 3) é um *downcasting*. Veja mais sobre isso [**nessa outra pergunta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131091/132).

Comment: Victor muito brigada pelo esclarecimento, ajudou-me bastante

Comment: @Rita Neste caso, se não lhe restar mais nenhuma dúvida acerca desta pergunta, clique no ✅ que aparece abaixo do número de votação desta resposta para marcá-la como aceita e marcar a sua pergunta como resolvida. Foi um prazer ajudá-la. 